How do I make "Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU" go away when using selenium?
Whenever I use my program, it gives the info thing "Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU", and it is in a bad position because it blocks a place where I am to input text.
I have heard someone else say "According to https://github.com/google-ai-edge/mediapipe/issues/3017 the message "Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU" is an info message. You can suppress it by simply adding options.add_argument('--log-level=1') to your webdriver's options." but I have no clue how you are supposed to add somthing to my webdriver options, or what webdriver options even are.

This is an example to set options for selenium webdriver and suppress the message. *selenium4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--log-level=1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")


